# Which of the following quantities and operations constitute vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following quantities and operations constitute vector spaces? If it is
a vector space, what dimension does it have? (Remember that the dimension can also be
infinite.) Justify your answers.

(a) The subset $X = \{(x, y) \in R^2 |xy = 0\}$ of $R^2$ with vector addition and scalar multiplication;

Not particularly good at linear algebra but I'm confident that this is a vector space. I don't know how to find the dimension of this vector space, I suppose I need to find a basis first?

Comment: It's not a vector space.  You need to start with the most basic properties of vector spaces: they have to be closed under the addition and scalar multiplication operations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it because if I try to check the requirement for being closed under addition ,  one pair of the 4 vectors wont equal zero since none of the vectors are the same?

Comment: What was your intuition as to why this would be a vector space? I know you realize now that it's not, but perhaps if you tell us what you were thinking we can help point out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Any vector in $X$ is of the form $(x,0)$ or $(0,y)$ for real numbers $x$ and $y$. Now take $x=y=1$ and add the vectors $(1,0)+(0,1)$ to get $(1,1)$. As you can see that this new vector is not in $X$ as $1\times 1 \ne 0$.

Thus, the subset $X$ is not closed under addition(assuming you are working with the usual definition of addition). So, it is not a subspace.